# [object HTMLTablerowElement]

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem, trying to create a button with Ajax/Php which is to appear on my main page and is supposed to have a onclick function. To be more specific, I end up in a while loop, which fetches through the rows of my mySQL-table and displays the following:

```
echo "<table>";
while($result == true && $a <= 15){
        $res = $result["uberschrift"];
        echo "<tr id='$res'>";
        echo "<td>".$a."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$res."</td>";
        echo "<td>"."<button id='b_löschen' onclick='k_löschen($res)'> löschen </button>"."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        $a++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

In fact, this works quite well, and on my main page the string contained in `$result["uberschrift"]` is displayed properly. However, if I call the function k_löschen with $res as shown above, it will not take the String but a certain
`[object HTMLTablerowElement]` as input, which naturally causes an Error. Can someone tell me how to change the code so that the function actually takes the string as it's input?

Comment: Yes, I needed to add `\"".$res."\"`. Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your quotes. Also you could tell us what $res typically contained.

I would do this

```
echo "<tr id=\"".$res."\">";
echo "<td><button id='b_löschen' onclick='k_löschen(\"".$res."\")'>löschen</button></td>";
```